# Is it possible with Padre to run and debug Perl scripts with a different Perl version?

Tags: perl, padre

[Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) is a (open) IDE for [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) that does look promising.

Since Padre is written in Perl itself, it is not apparent whether it's easily possible and *practicable* to run and debug Perl scripts in this IDE that are running on a different Perl version than the IDE itself.

As an example, say I download the [current installer](http://padre.perlide.org/download.html) (for Windows) which will install and run *Padre on Strawberry Perl 5.12* -- can I then use this IDE to run+debug my scripts that are running on *ActiveState Perl 5.8.9*? <sub>(Yes, and I want them to run exactly on AS+5.8.9 because this is where they'll run in production.)</sub>

I am aware that there is a Padre package for AS+5.8.9 but I would much rather install the default IDE package and have the IDE run on the Perl it normally runs on and have my scripts run on the Perl they normally run on.

Insights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Tools->Preferences->Language - Perl 5 you can specify the perl binary as well as its parameters to run your projects.

Comment: Any comment wrt to debugging in such a scenario?